# javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call while using an f:convertNumber inside a p/h:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, validation, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to use an `<f:convertNumber>` inside a `<p:dataTable>` like the following.

```
<p:column headerText="Text">
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{country.countryCode}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:inputText value="#{country.countryCode}" required="true">
                <f:validateLength minimum="1" maximum="45"/>
                <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" type="number"/>
            </p:inputText>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

Where `country.countryCode` is a String type property in the associated data model.

I'm getting the following exception:

```
INFO:   javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validatePropertyForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:855)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validatePropertyForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:768)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateValueInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:725)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateValue(ValidatorImpl.java:184)
    at javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.validate(BeanValidator.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validateValue(UIInput.java:1165)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:983)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1249)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
    at org.primefaces.component.celleditor.CellEditor.processValidators(CellEditor.java:82)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.process(UIData.java:339)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processChildren(UIData.java:323)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processPhase(UIData.java:285)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processValidators(UIData.java:259)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.processValidators(DataTable.java:622)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:592)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:692)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:406)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:269)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1193)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.SizeValidatorForCharSequence.isValid(SizeValidatorForCharSequence.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:281)
    ... 73 more

WARNING:   javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:276)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1193)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validatePropertyForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:855)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validatePropertyForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:768)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateValueInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:725)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateValue(ValidatorImpl.java:184)
    at javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.validate(BeanValidator.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validateValue(UIInput.java:1165)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:983)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1249)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
    at org.primefaces.component.celleditor.CellEditor.processValidators(CellEditor.java:82)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.process(UIData.java:339)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processChildren(UIData.java:323)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processPhase(UIData.java:285)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processValidators(UIData.java:259)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.processValidators(DataTable.java:622)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:592)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:692)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:406)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:269)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.SizeValidatorForCharSequence.isValid(SizeValidatorForCharSequence.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:281)
    ... 73 more

SEVERE:   javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validatePropertyForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:855)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validatePropertyForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:768)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateValueInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:725)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateValue(ValidatorImpl.java:184)
    at javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.validate(BeanValidator.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validateValue(UIInput.java:1165)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:983)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1249)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
    at org.primefaces.component.celleditor.CellEditor.processValidators(CellEditor.java:82)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.process(UIData.java:339)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processChildren(UIData.java:323)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processPhase(UIData.java:285)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processValidators(UIData.java:259)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.processValidators(DataTable.java:622)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:592)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:692)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:406)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:269)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1193)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.SizeValidatorForCharSequence.isValid(SizeValidatorForCharSequence.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:281)
    ... 73 more
```

Why doesn't `<f:convertNumber>` work inside a `<p:dataTable>`? Can it be made to work?

Answer (score 1):

By convention (design) [validators run after converters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462909/invocation-sequence-of-jsf-converters-and-validators) since they should always validate the 'busininess' objects, not the textual value send by the client.

So the (explicit) `f:convertNumber` runs first, converting the value that is posted from the client to a `java.lang.Long` in this case. Next the `f:validateLength` is run and that validator expects a `java.lang.String` since that is the [definition of this `f:validateLength`](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jsf-page-core003.html), validate the length of a **string** (not a number). But the Integer object can be 'treated' as a string but you'll get the hash value then which has its length validated, **NOT** the content. It will not crash but won't work as you expect it.

So effectively you are using a wrong combination of validator and converter. Even more so since you seem to be storing the countryCode as a varChar again, but convert it to a number (`Long`) first. Since you also seem to have constraints on the entities, JSF automagically fires a validation for that field and in that step, it tries to do validations on these. In that step, the classCast occurs.

Then there is no need to convert to a number first, but the `f:validateLength` in combination with a `f:validateRegex pattern="[0-9]*"` should be enough like @Tiny already stated. Heck, if you have constraints on the entities, there is no need for the validators in the UI at all.

Answer (score 0):

I never had any problems using `<f:convertNumber>` inside a `<p:dataTable>` and a simple playground example seems to work fine with me

Your actual error is caused by this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
```

Try to locate where you are trying to parse a long. Perhaps its a long in the DB and you are trying to put it in a String?

Comment: I don't parse `countryCode` to `Long` anywhere. The `country_code` column in the database is of type `VARCHAR(45)` which is mapped by a corresponding property of type String in JPA. The exception occurs only when `<f:convertNumber>` is used inside a `<p:dataTable>` or `<h:dataTable>`. It works intuitively otherwise.

Comment: I don't know the reason behind the exception but I think `<f:convertNumber>` should not be used intuitively (it is a converter), when there a column of type `VARCHAR(size)` representing a property of type String in the model (while I'm uncertain about whether or not `<f:convertNumber>` can be used in this situation). I simply use `<f:validateRegex pattern="[0-9]*" />` to suffice the requirement to allow only digits in the given `<p:inputText>`. Using the given regex, the associated `<p:inputText>` can also be left blank to delegate the required validation to `required="true"`.